# Regex to match repeated characters

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to create a regex that matches a string if it has a 3 or more repetitive characters in a row (e.g. aaaaaa, testtttttt, otttttter).

I have tried the following:

```
regexp.Compile("[A-Za-z0-9]{3,}")
regexp.Compile("(.){3,}")
regexp.Compile("(.)\\1{3,}")
```

which matches *any* 3 characters in a row, but not *consecutive* characters... Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Apparently Go's flavor of regex doesn't support [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) which would normally be the way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're asking for cannot be done with *true* regular expressions, what you need are (irregular) backreferences. While many regexp engines implement them, RE2 used by Go does not. RE2 is a fast regexp engine that guarantees linear time string processing, but there's no known way to implement backreferences with such efficiency. (See https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/ for further information.)

To solve your problem you may want to search for some other regexp library. I believe bindings for PCRE can be found, but I've no personal experience from them.

Another approach would be to parse the string manually without using (ir)regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the ugly solution, you could automatically generate it:

```
A{3,}|B{3,}|...|Z{3,}|a{3,}|b{3,}|...|z{3,}|0{3,}|1{3,}|...|9{3,}
```

Answer (score 3):

Due to the problems stated, I eventually settled on the following non-regex solution:

```
norm = "this it a ttttt"
repeatCount := 1
thresh := 3
lastChar := ""
for _, r := range norm {
    c := string(r)
    if c == lastChar {
        repeatCount++
        if repeatCount == thresh {
            break
        }
    } else {
        repeatCount = 1
    }
    lastChar = c
}
```